# concatenate all imports into one scss file

Tags: sass

I'm currently working on a [SASS library](https://github.com/varemenos/verepo) which is a long list of partials imported into 1 file.

The file structure is as following:

```
css-directory
├── functions
│   ├── _px2em.scss
│   └── _unitless.scss
├── helpers
│   ├── _align.scss
│   ├── _clearfix.scss
│   ├── _float.scss
│   ├── _hidden.scss
│   ├── _invisible.scss
│   ├── _ir.scss
│   └── _visuallyhidden.scss
├── layout
│   ├── _blockquote.scss
│   ├── _button.scss
│   ├── _fixed-footer.scss
│   ├── _form.scss
│   ├── _list.scss
│   ├── _loading.scss
│   ├── _triangle.scss
│   └── _truncate.scss
├── modules
│   ├── _grid.scss
│   └── _normalize.scss
├── prefixes
│   ├── _animation-delay.scss
│   ├── _animation.scss
│   ├── _background-clip.scss
│   ├── _borderbox.scss
│   ├── _border-radius.scss
│   ├── _box-shadow.scss
│   ├── _box-sizing.scss
│   ├── _flex.scss
│   ├── _font-face.scss
│   ├── _gradient.scss
│   ├── _hyphens.scss
│   ├── _keyframes.scss
│   ├── _transform-origin.scss
│   ├── _transform.scss
│   ├── _transition.scss
│   └── _user-select.scss
└── _verepo.scss
```

and the `_verepo.scss` file imports all the other partials.

I'd like to be able to concatenate `_verepo.scss` and it's partials into 1 `.scss` file so that I can then distribute it easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS or LESS packaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949004/sass-or-less-packaging)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, by using `grunt` and `grunt-contrib-concat`.

Fixed it with the following code block inside of grunt's initConfig:

```
concat: {
        options: {
                banner: '/*! veRepo.scss v%VERSION% | MIT License | https://github.com/varemenos/verepo */\n\n'
        },
        dist: {
                src: [
                        'src/functions/_**.scss',
                        'src/prefixes/_**.scss',
                        'src/helpers/_**.scss',
                        'src/layout/_**.scss',
                        'src/modules/_**.scss',
                ],
                dest: '_verepo.scss'
        }
}
```