# Compass - Define paths

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Each bit of my project is a separate component, with its own hierarchy. To include them in my file, I just need to include the `app.js`and inject it to whatever I want. So for each component, I have a separate `config.rb` file to run the compass for it.

Now, say I have the following hierarchy:

```
/app
    config.rb
    /assets
        /sass
            _functions.scss
        /css
    /components
        /login
            /assets
                /sass
                    app.scss
                /css
            config.rb
```

Say I want to `@import` `_functions.scss` into `app.scss`. Right now, I have to use the relative path , and basically keep on going back the root folder, and then go into the folder for the file.

Is there a way to define the path inside the `login`'s `config.rb` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949004/sass-or-less-packaging

Comment: Not really what I asked? That is for creating extensions, I am not creating extensions. I just want to define a variable and use to @import other files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uses the [`add_import_path`](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) directive in your `config.rb`file, like I do in a project to access vendors mixins:

```
add_import_path "#{File.expand_path(sass_dir)}/vendors";
```

In your case, it would be:

```
add_import_path "#{File.expand_path('./assets/sass')}";
```