# Write a Gem which adds to the Sass load path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I've created a Gem which copies sass stylesheets to a specified install location. However, I'm now working on another Gem which will contain sass stylesheets which don't need to be copied to a project.

What I'm wanting to be able to do, if possible, is to add the path to the sass stylesheets within my gem and import them from there as opposed to including them in every single project which in the long term would be useless and potentially a headache to maintain.

For example, I create a gem called *sassext* which contains all the stylesheets. Then within my projects I can do the following;

```
@import 'sassext/foobar'
```

Ideally, I want to be able to use the sass --watch tools as opposed to create my own.

Cheers

P.S. Any links to relevant information/guides would also be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS or LESS packaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949004/sass-or-less-packaging)

Comment: @cimmanon Nope. That post suggest using compass which in not wanting to do